# Ruby Script to ping a URL every 30sec

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to ping a URL every 30 seconds using Ruby script?

```
require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com',80)
response = http.request_get('/')
p response.status
```

Comment: how about `while true` and `sleep(30)`

Comment: Every minute is easy if you're prepared to use `cron`.

Comment: @tadman sure thats not a problem.

Comment: Then it's as easy as `* * * * * ~/cron/myscript` in your [`crontab` file](https://corenominal.org/2016/05/12/howto-setup-a-crontab-file/). The advantage of that is it will run all the time, even after a reboot, without intervention.

Comment: does this work on MAC?

Comment: It works on macOS, yes, as that has a BSD core. (Note, it's not "MAC", that's [something else entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)).

Comment: @tadman thanks for correcting :)

Comment: Don't use a GET request, as it loads the network, server and your host unnecessarily. Instead use a HEAD request. That's part of being a good network citizen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your use case a simple `loop` with a `sleep` might to the job:

```
require 'net/http'

loop do
  http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com')
  response = http.request_get('/')
  p response.code

  sleep 30      
end
```

Comment: but what if server that serves the url will respond after 1 minute?

Comment: Can we do it like: `Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com',80, :read_timeout => 10)`  ?

Comment: @spickermann SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to www.google.com:80 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)

Comment: @num8er: As I said it depends on the use case. Is it important to ping every 30 seconds no matter what? Or ping 30 seconds after the last ping returned successful?

Comment: @HarshaMV: I updated my answer to address your comment. Works fine on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

This code pings every 30 sec, as long as the ping duration is less than 30 sec.

```
require 'net/http'

time_step = 30 #s

loop do
  start = Time.now
    http = Net::HTTP.new('www.google.com',80)
    response = http.request_get('/')
    p response.code # -> "302"
  duration = Time.now-start

  sleep (time_step - duration) unless duration > time_step
end
```